# Best option to narrow a known set of triangles?

Tags: collision-detection, physics, octree

I am building collision detection and response in a custom engine. This routine happens between the moving player, and static entities on the map.

In the first phase, the broad phase I am moving the player and looking for any new AABB to AABB collisions between the player and static entities.

In the second phase, the narrow phase. I then do a swept-spehere to triangle detection. I move the players collision sphere through the triangles in the colliding AABB.This phase can be expensive because the colliding AABB may have complicated geometry with many triangles.

I need to narrow down the set of triangles being detected. Some solutions I have in mind are:

- Get the "overlap box" the space where both AABB's overlap in the broad phase.

  Then do a pass on all the triangles in the colliding AABB and return just the ones in the overlap box. 
  My understanding here is I'll have to use a SAT algorithm to detect if the AABB and triangles collide or not and I'll still have to iterate over all the triangles in the colliding AABB. I'm not sure if this is any more performant.
- Sort the triangles by distance to the AABB collision

  If I sort the triangles by their distance to the AABB collision I will be able to exit from the narrow phase before the entire set of triangles has been processed. 
  I'm not sure what the performance implications of resorting the triangles each frame would be. I'm thinking not great...
- Use a spatial partitioning data structure OctTree or quadTree to narrow down the triangles.

  It may be extensive work to build one of these structures together for my engine and populate it with all the entities triangles. I'm not sure if they will give me any improved granularity. Will they be more precise than the AABB overlap?

I wanted to ask for help first before I start building one these solutions and reviewing the performance. Any other ideas are greatly appreciated.

Comment: The very best way to find out which of these options performs best in your implementation, with your mesh data, is to code it and profile it. Then you have empirical proof. Anything else is just Internet hearsay.

Comment: @DMGregory so none of these options look obviously better or worse than the others? like the SAT filter on the AABB overlap seems like a viable option vs an Octtree?

Comment: It might not even matter, depending on your typical load. That's why you have to profile, to find out how they actually behave with your implementation, and your data, in the context of how they're used in your game.